# Change Queue Manager Hostname or IP Address Dynamically in IBM Integration Bus

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am facing a problem, which is that i want to set all the MQ details for MQ node in IBM Integration Bus from ESQL file. As I have all the MQ details are setup in database so I would get details from there and set to MQ node so the messages will go to queue dynamically.

I read some stuff about LocalEnvironment variables I have set it in ESQL file but the values of those variables are not reflecting on MQ node. Below is the way I am setting up my node property;

```
SET OutputRoot.MQMD.ReplyToQ = 'AMLQUEUE2';
```

As I am using 'MQReply' Node for sending messages. I would like to set the hostname because I am looking for the hostname property but its not there I think. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This ReplyToQ only works with you are using MQReply Node to output the message.

For setting a dynamic destination queue you must use "Destination List" in a MQOutput Node.

In the MQOutput Documatation search for Destination Mode --> [MQOutput](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac04570_.htm)

For populating the Local Environment for setting a destination list see the [addToMQDestinationList procedure](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac16862_.htm).